# Function to extract data from pdf

Tags: r, function, for-loop, pdf

I am trying to use a function to extract a data from a few hundred pdf documents. All the documents follow the same format so the initial set up was pretty easy. However, when I tried to build a function from that code I was unable to get it to work.

Here is a simplified version of my code where I am extracting a LOT number from each pdf document:

```
# Load the required library
library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)

root_folder <- "P:\\Data Transfer\\Fortessa 245\\Lucas\\Achilles Base 2Blue 3Red 6Vio 3YG 4UV"

pdf_files <- list.files(path = root_folder, 
                        pattern = "*.pdf", 
                        recursive = TRUE, 
                        full.names = TRUE)



extract_cstLOT <- function(pdf_file){
  # read in a PDF file
  pdf_file <- pdf_text(pdf_file)
    # Use str_split to split the text into lines
  lines <- data.frame(str_split(pdf_file, "\n") %>% unlist())
    #extract CST lot from lines
  cstLOT <- lapply(lines$str_split.pdf_file....n.......unlist..[13], function(x) {
    split_result <- str_split(x, "  ")
    if (length(split_result) == 0) {
      return(list(x))
    } else {
      return(split_result[[1]])
    }
  })
  # Remove empty elements from each column
  cstLOT <- lapply(cstLOT, function(x) x[x != ""])
  #convert to dataframe
  cstLOT <- t(data.frame(cstLOT))
  #remove row names
  rownames(cstLOT)<-NULL
  #extract cst lot as a numeric object
  cstLOT <- as.numeric(cstLOT[,2])
  
  return(cstLOT)
}

all_CST<-as.data.frame("")
for (n in length(pdf_files)) {
  current_CST<-extract_cstLOT(pdf_file = pdf_files[n])
  all_CST<-cbind(all_CST, current_CST)
}
```

This code will only read in 1 pdf and give me that lost number. Where am I going wrong?

Session info:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pdftools_3.3.3  forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.4.1   dplyr_1.0.10    purrr_0.3.5     readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.2.1     tibble_3.1.8    ggplot2_3.4.0   tidyverse_1.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9          pillar_1.8.1        compiler_4.2.2      cellranger_1.1.0    dbplyr_2.2.1        tools_4.2.2         timechange_0.1.1    lubridate_1.9.0    
 [9] jsonlite_1.8.3      googledrive_2.0.0   lifecycle_1.0.3     gargle_1.2.1        gtable_0.3.1        pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_1.0.6         reprex_2.0.2       
[17] DBI_1.1.3           cli_3.4.1           rstudioapi_0.14     haven_2.5.1         xml2_1.3.3          withr_2.5.0         httr_1.4.4          askpass_1.1        
[25] generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.5.1         fs_1.5.2            hms_1.1.2           googlesheets4_1.0.1 grid_4.2.2          tidyselect_1.2.0    glue_1.6.2         
[33] qpdf_1.3.0          R6_2.5.1            fansi_1.0.3         readxl_1.4.1        tzdb_0.3.0          modelr_0.1.10       magrittr_2.0.3      ellipsis_0.3.2     
[41] backports_1.4.1     scales_1.2.1        rvest_1.0.3         assertthat_0.2.1    colorspace_2.0-3    utf8_1.2.2          stringi_1.7.8       munsell_0.5.0      
[49] broom_1.0.1         crayon_1.5.2
```

Comment: `length(pdf_files)` gives the number of files. Hence your loop will only read the last element of your file names list. Try with `for (pdf in pdf_files) {  current_CST<-extract_cstLOT(pdf_file = pdf) ... }` instead.

Comment: other options include changing the for loop to `n in 1:length(pdf_files)`, `n in seq_along(pdf_files)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stefan and DJ in the comments for spotting this.

It turns out there was a typo in my for loop. The fixed code works just fine :)

```
all_CST<-as.data.frame("")
for (n in 1:length(pdf_files)) {
  current_CST<-extract_cstLOT(pdf_file = pdf_files[n])
  all_CST<-cbind(all_CST, current_CST)
}
```